# How can I ensure that WCF web http binding always emits type information for JSON?

Tags: json, wcf, webhttpbinding

I am using the WebHttpBinding provided by WCF. When making requests in Json, the response does not contain any type information.

How can I ensure that type information is emitted when using the WebHttpBinding for Json requests?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Either:

1 User proper **Accept header** (= "application/json") on client side. Framework should work it out automatically.

or:

2 Specify OperationContract with attribute: `WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ...)`

Comment: I am using that. Its just that type information is not getting emitted on the service side by the serializer.